# How do I defined unique constraint in xsd ? How can I achive error validation using xml-libxml?

Tags: perl, xsd, xml-libxml

With reference to topic,
[Perl, LibXML and Schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658060/perl-libxml-and-schemas)

If I want to make the isbn tag to be an unique constraint, then what will be the change required in XSD. In addition to this, if I want to add validations for unique constraint using XML::LibXml, can I achieve the validations check using the same code? Can someone please explain with sample example with error in xml doc for unique constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In regards of XSD schema enforcing key uniqueness: use the `xs:unique` element. More info in [Enforcing Association Cardinality](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/987) article, and take a look at the provided [example XSD](http://www.xml.com/2002/06/26/examples/Restaurant.xsd.txt);
- XML schema validation in Perl can be achieved using [XML::Compile](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aCompile) module, which wraps itself around XML::LibXML.

Answer (score 0):

xsd allows the amount of an item could appear, add this to your isbn element xsd declaration

```
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
```